# subjects.map is not a function error when updating state when using array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

my 'handleGrade' function is giving an error when I try to update the grade value when received.

```
function Sgpa() {
  const [subjects, setSubjects] = useState([
    {
      name: "subject name",
      credits: 3,
      points: 0,
      grade: "B+"
    }
  ]);
  const [sgpa, setSgpa] = useState(0);
  function handleAdd() {
    setSubjects((prevValues) => [
      ...prevValues,
      {
        name: "subject name",
        credits: 3,
        points: 3,
        grade: "B+"
      }
    ]);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    calcSgpa();
  });




  function calcSgpa() {
    let totalCredits = 0;
    let totalPoints = 0;
    subjects.map((subject, i) => {
      totalCredits += subject.credits;
      totalPoints += subject.points;
    });
    setSgpa((totalCredits * totalPoints) / totalCredits);
  }
```

The error is down below. I'm receiving the correct value from event.target and I think I'm failing to update the value inside my array of objects.

```
  function handleGrade(event, i) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setSubjects(...subjects,{ ...subjects[i] , grade:event.target.value });
    console.log(subjects);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Sgpa : {sgpa}</h3>
      {subjects.map((subject, i) => {
        return (
          <SgpaComponent subject={subject} key={i} handleGrade={handleGrade} />
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You still need to set an array, so spread into the array rather than the arguments of setSubjects like so: `setSubjects([...subjects,{ ...subjects[i], grade:event.target.value }]);`

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing? Can we see where you call `handleGrade()`?

Comment: subjects.map is not a function

Comment: @AliQumail I think you need to provide us with more code so that we can see what's going on, `subjects.map` isn't even in your question. Can you show the code where you use it please? I think we need to see quite a bit more code in order to be able to help

Comment: @NickParsons it worked Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

map error happens because,

```
setSubjects(...subjects,{ ...subjects[i] , grade:event.target.value });
```

Here, you are setting objects instead of array of objects. "..." will pull everything out of array and you forgot to create a new array while pulling everything out. After that you are trying to map the subjects, where it is not an array anymore.

You can do this is in several ways. One of the best way is instead of changing old state directly, you can copy the old state and update that. Finally return the new updated state. Every setState in react will accept the function, which will give you the old state value.

Code will look like this after changes

```
function handleGrade(event, i) {
    setSubjects(oldSubjects => {
        let newSubjects = [...oldSubjects];
        newSubjects[i] = {
           ...newSubjects[i],
           grade: event.target.value
        };
        return newSubjects;
    });
}
```

Hope it answered your question.

Comment: grade value is undefined although event.target.value log correctly.

Comment: try console.log(newSubjects); before return it.